# Rails: Return value from another table after a select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, default-value

I had a question that was marked as a duplicate but it really didn't answer my question, but it did answer another question that I had so that was great :) I think perhaps I did not explain myself correctly so going to try again.  Please keep in mind that I am still relatively new to RoR.  My previous question can be found here:

[Rails: Select on 1 field returns value to another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23271672/rails-select-on-1-field-returns-value-to-another-field)

So, let me explain what I am trying to achieve again.  I have a table called plans and a table called plan_prices.  A plan has many plan prices.  I have another table called contracts.  A contract can have a plan and a plan price, so the contract table has plan_id and plan_price_id.  So here is what I am trying to achieve.  When I create a contract I have a select for the plan which returns the plan_id.  I also have a select on the plan_price that returns the plan_price_id.  This first select has some JS on it to determine when it changes so that the plan_price is filtered accordingly.  All this is working just fine.  The final piece that I want to do is when I select the plan_price there is a column on that table called price.  I want to take this price and default it into the contract.price field which can then be changed if the user deems necessary.  I am just having a hard time working out how I would default the plan_price.price value into the contract.price field once the plan_price has been selected.  The contract.price field is a simple free entry field and not a select field, since the user can change the price to something else.

Hope the above is clear and I hope that there is someone that can help me out on this.

TIA.

Comment: as far as i understand, you want to update a text-field for the price to have the value of the selected plan-price?

Comment: That is correct, yes.

Comment: i'd recommend storing all the price objects as json on a html node and  change the value of the input field accordingly. the proposed solution using ajax is way to complex for this simple task

Comment: phoet, I am still new to rails, can you provide perhaps an example? I'd have no idea where to even start on this.

Answer (score 0):

Send an Ajax request on the onchange state of the plan_price field:

```
:onchange=>"selectPrize(this)"
```

You will be passing the selected value as a param on your AJAX request

JS Function

```
 function selectPrize(prizeID) {    
        var dataString ='prize='+prizeID.value;
        $.ajax({  
        type: "GET",  
        url: "/your_controller/your_controller_method",  
        data: dataString  
         });          
         return false;
    };
```

On your controller, in the selected method, look for the plan prize with the id you got through your ajax request.

```
@plan_prize = Planprize.where("id = #{params[:prize]}").first
```

Then create a js.erb file in your folder, depending on the method you've chosen in your controller and do some simple javascript to change the value of the contract_prize:

your_method.js.erb file

```
$(document.getElementById('contract_prize').value = '<%= @plan_prize.prize %>');
```

This should work.

Comment: I could not get this to work for me Oscar.  I have tried to enter the details of what I have done but the comments box is not big enough :( Anyway, followed what you had but it didn't work.  The price did not populate in the field once I had changed the price list.

Comment: Have you checked if there's any JS error? Also, im sure this is not the most practical way of doing this, but its the only one i can think of.

Comment: I didn't see any errors, but I am still quite new to rails and perhaps I was looking in the wrong place.  I basically redesigned the form now to handle this, not the most elegant way but the best way I could come up with.  I was hoping phoet would elaborate on his answer.

Comment: Thanks.  Not using JS, just getting the user to save information first on the first few fields, and then it throws them into edit mode and that is when I populate the price.  Like I said, not the most elegant but works :)